# C# - Silverlight - CustomAttribute with Enum

Tags: c#, enums, getcustomattributes

I have the following class:

```
[MetadataAttribute]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ModuleActivationButtonAttribute : ExportAttribute
{
    public Enum TargetRegion { get; set; }

    public ModuleActivationButtonAttribute(Enum targetRegion) : base(typeof(IModuleActivationButton))
    {
        TargetRegion = targetRegion;
    }
}
```

The class compiles fine, but when I decorate my property with it:

```
[ModuleActivationButton(Regions.Tabs)]
public IModuleActivationButton ModuleActivationButton
{
    get { return new ModuleActivationButton() as IModuleActivationButton; }
    set { ModuleActivationButton = value; }
}

public enum Regions
{
    Content,
    Tabs
}
```

The compiler spits out:

> `Error    1   An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type  C:\...\CompanyX.Modules.Home\HomeModule.cs  28  33  CompanyX.Modules.Home`

Comment: platform,language, and compiler, please

Comment: Ok, I've deleted my response because I'm not convinced it helps you and I don't know enough about MEF to go much further. But you might want to include a bit more detail about what you're trying to do; looking at the example of ExportAttribute on MSDN, I think you may be using it wrong. It seems to have Exports on classes and Imports on properties.

Comment: According to: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.exportattribute.aspx you can export on classes and properties and methods and fields.

Comment: It seems that I can box the enum to an object and pass it as that, then unbox it when I interpret the metadata. But then I can enforce this only by throwing an exception if upon interpreting it does not unbox to an Enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I can box the enum to an object and pass it as that, then unbox. But then I can enforce this only by throwing an exception if upon interpreting it does not unbox to an Enum

```
[MetadataAttribute]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ModuleActivationButtonAttribute : ExportAttribute
{
    public Enum TargetRegion { get; set; }

    public ModuleActivationButtonAttribute(object targetRegion) : base(typeof(IModuleActivationButton))
    {
        TargetRegion = targetRegion as Enum;
    }
}
```